# How do I locate a file / folder which is too long and bars me from uploading to OneDrive

Tags: windows-search, filenames

I have a file/folder which is preventing me from uploading to OneDrive.  I did not generate this file/folder and after 3 complete searches of my PC I cannot locate the file/folder. However, according to OneDrive the name is:

> C:\Users\iseul_000\OneDrive\Desktop\DROPBOX\BACKUP files, Aileen, Louis, Iseult\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Pepper Data\ShockWave Flash\YWPD7WHE\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys#cfiles.5min.com.\settings.sol

Please tell me how to find this file/folder so that I can shorten the name and thus allow uploading of OneDrive files & folders, as advised by OneDrive on-screen whenever I do try to upload.

Comment: Are you searching with hidden and system files included?

Comment: Hi David ~As far as I know I have searched including system files.  However, I hadn't heard of 'hidden' files and so do not know if they are automatically searched as well when a search of every file & folder in a PC is commenced.  Thank you for your post.  Kind regards, Iseult. Iseult Catherine O'Brien.